# DB design for sensor data (lots and LOTS of data)

Tags: database, database-design, large-data

I am writing an application for viewing and management of sensor data. I can have unlimited number of sensors, and each sensors makes one reading every minutes and records the values as **(time, value, sensor_id, location_id, [a bunch of other doubles]).**

As an example, I might have 1000 sensors and collect data every minute for each one of them, which ends up generating 525,600,000 rows after a year. Multiple users (say up to 20) can plot the data of any time period, zoom in and out in any range, and add annotations to the data of a sensor at a time. Users can also modify certain data points and I need to keep track of the raw data and modified one.

I'm not sure how the database for application like this should look like! Should it be just one table SensorData, with indices for time and sensor_id and location_id? Should I partition this single table based on sensor_id? should I save the data in files for each sensor each day (say .csv files) and load them into a temp table upon request? How should I manage annotations?

I have not decided on a DBMS yet (maybe MySQL or PostgreSQL). But my intention is to get an insight about data management in applications like this in general.

Comment: You are correct that time, sensor_id, and location_id are the columns to possibly index.  Only you can tell us which column is the most important.  When I worked in seismic exploration, time was the most important column.  Location id was only necessary to correct the time for the distance.  You need to tell us which column(s) are the most important columns for selection.

Comment: Current relational databases can hold trillions and trillions of rows.  The number of rows is no longer a concern with modern relational databases.

Comment: Does the location for a sensor change over time?

Comment: How often does new sensor reading data need to be made visible to users? Is it near real-time, or hourly, or daily ...?

Comment: Would you expect that the data retrieval should be optimised to read all readings for particular sensors, or all reading for particular time slices?

Comment: Location doesn't change. Daily. There are few commonly used filters. Viewing data per location, or per sensor, for long periods of time (1 year ~ 2 years) is very common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for an answer I came across this thread. While it is not entirely the same as my case, it answers many of my questions; such as is using a relational database a reasonable way of doing this (to which the answer is "Yes"), and what to do about partitioning, maintenance, archiving, etc.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13882/database-redesign-opportunity-what-table-design-to-use-for-this-sensor-data-col

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the the users cannot change the fields you show (time, value, sensor_id, location_id) but the other fields implied.

In that case, I would suggest Version Normal Form. The fields you name are static, that is, once entered, they never change. However, the other fields are changeable by many users.

You fail to state if users see all user's changes or only their own. I will assume all changes are seen by all users. You should be able to make the appropriate changes if that assumption is wrong.

First, let's explain Version Normal Form. As you will see, it is just a special case of Second Normal Form.

Take a tuple of the fields you have named, rearranged to group the key values together:

```
R1( sensor_id(k), time(k), location_id, value )
```

As you can see, the location_id (assuming the sensors are movable) and value are dependent on the sensor that generated the value and the time the measurement was made. This tuple is in 2nf.

Now you want to add updatable fields:

```
R2( sensor_id(k), time(k), location_id, value, user_id, date_updated, ... )
```

But the updateable fields (contained in the ellipses) are dependent not only on the original key fields but also on user_id and date_updated. The tuple is no longer in 2nf.

So we add the new fields not to the original tuple, but create a normalized tuple:

```
R1( sensor_id(k), time(k), location_id, value )
Rv( sensor_id(k), time(k), user_id(k), date_updated(k), ... )
```

This makes it possible to have a series of any number of versions for each original reading.

To query the latest update for a particular reading:

```
select  R1.sensor_id, R1.time, R1.location_id, R1.value, R2.user_id, R2.date_updated, R2.[...]
from    R1
left join Rv as R2
    on  R2.sensor_id = R1.sensor_id
    and R2.time = R1.time
    and R2.date_updated =(
        select max( date_update )
        from    Rv
        where   sensor_id = R2.sensor_id
            and time = R2.time )
where   R1.sensor_id = :ThisSensor
    and R1.time = :ThisTime;
```

To query the latest update for a particular reading made by a particular user, just add the user_id value to the filtering criteria of the main query and subquery. It should be easy to see how to get all the updates for a particular reading or just those made by a specific user.

This design is very flexible in how you can access the data and, because the key fields are also indexed, it is very fast even on Very Large Tables.

Comment: Thanks, yes, all the changes are viewable by all users. You went straight to the annotations. So you think a relational database is the correct way of solving this problem?... After 2 years I will have a table with 1 trillion rows! I'm starting to create the database with the following considerations ... let me know if you think these assumptions are ok:
I will create an archiving strategy to push everything older than two years to an archive table (daily).
I will have my table partitioned based on sensor_id. And I'll have indices on the time, location and sensor_id.

Comment: I'm not a DBA so I can't advise you on things like partitioning. However, archiving strategies are a good idea. You need to balance how much data you want "online" against how far back you and your users need to easily go. Users can perfectly handle the idea that if data is needed that is, say, more than two years old, they just have to use a different screen.